# Angular 2 unit test service stub value does not change?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am working through Angular 2 testing examples here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

Welcome component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService }       from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  template: '<h3 class="welcome" ><i>{{welcome}}</i></h3>'
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  welcome = '-- not initialized yet --';
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {     
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.welcome = this.userService.isLoggedIn ?
      'Welcome, ' + this.userService.user.name :
      'Please log in.';
  }
}
```

Test spec

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {
  let component: WelcomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WelcomeComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;
  let userServiceStub: UserService;
  let userService:UserService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // Declare stub UserService for test purposes
    let userServiceStub = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: { name: 'Test User'}
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
       providers:  [ {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);

    //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.welcome'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should welcome the user', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const content = el.textContent;
    expect(content).toContain('Welcome', '"Welcome ..."');
    expect(content).toContain('Test User', 'expected name');
  });

  it('should welcome "Bubba"', () => {
    userService.user.name = 'Bubba'; 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('Bubba');
  });

  it('should request login if not logged in', () => {
    userService.isLoggedIn = false; 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const content = el.textContent;
    expect(content).not.toContain('Welcome', 'not welcomed');
    expect(content).toMatch(/log in/i, '"log in"');
  });

});
```

The last 2 it() tests failed because the service stub values didn't change after

```
userService.user.name = 'Bubba';
fixture.detectChanges();
```

and

```
userService.isLoggedIn = false; 
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Any idea why Angular test module failed to detect change?

**Uodate**

I found it. `fixture.detectChanges()` triggers `ngOnInit()`. 
`fixture.detectChanges()` in `beforeEach()` is the culprit. Because it has initialized the component, the `fixture.detectChanges()` in `it()` won't initialized the component again. So by removing `fixture.detectChanges()` from `beforeEach()` the `fixture.detectChanges()` in `it()` will have the chance to trigger `ngOnInit()` and all tests pass through.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);

    //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.welcome'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
    // fixture.detectChanges(); // this is the culprit.
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem in the same bit of code. Don't know why I had that line in `beforeEach()`. It would be nice if that was explained on the [testing page](https://angular.io/guide/testing#automatic-change-detection)

Comment: It seems also to be a problem if you use `ComponentFixtureAutoDetect` in the setup and `fixture.detectChanges()` in the test.

Answer (score 2):

Try to initilize your service at your "it"

```
 it('should welcome "Bubba"' , inject([UserService], (userService: UserService) => {
     userService.user.name = 'Bubba'; 
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(el.textContent).toContain('Bubba');
  }));
```

Comment: Yoav, I found the problem and updated my post. I still upvoted you for your answer because it helped me clear my thoughts.

Comment: can you post your solution?

Comment: Sure. Just posted.

Comment: Actually, I do want 'component.fixtureChanges' in BeforeEach function and also I want to change the service properties in run time and access it.. This helped me with my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

welcome.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {
  let component: WelcomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WelcomeComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;
  let userServiceStub: UserService;
  let userService:UserService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // Declare stub UserService for test purposes
    let userServiceStub = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: { name: 'Test User'}
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
      providers:  [ {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // UserService from the root injector
    //userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);

    //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.welcome'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should welcome the user', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const content = el.textContent;
    expect(content).toContain('Welcome', '"Welcome ..."');
    expect(content).toContain('Test User', 'expected name');
  });

  it('should welcome "Bubba"',  () => {
    userService.user.name = 'Bubba'; 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('Bubba');
  });

  it('should request login if not logged in', () => {
    userService.isLoggedIn = false; 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const content = el.textContent;
    expect(content).not.toContain('Welcome', 'not welcomed');
    expect(content).toMatch(/log in/i, '"log in"');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Thanks to [redOctober13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406483/redoctober13) to point out the issues:

1. If you have **ComponentFixtureAutoDetect** in the providers array of
   TestBed configuration and you use fixture.detectChanges(), It won't
   work inside **it()**. ComponentFixtureAutoDetect worked perfectly
   fine with html changes like input etc, but somehow it failed here.
2. Remove fixture.detectChanges() from **beforeEach**() and use it after updating the name in **it()**.